# Where did the Inhumans end up on Earth?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, inhumans

At the end of episode 8, their Attillan is about destroyed and one of the Nasa/Government guys says "I know where you can stay" and in the final scene, they're all in this area.

Do we know where they settled?    Government base?   Area 51?   Xanadu?   The Plaza Hotel?    I'm curious if there's an official or comic-sourced answer.   It wouldn't be someplace hidden like [Afterlife](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Afterlife), because a high-ranking government employee suggested it.

Comment: @Paulie_D  I know there's no guarantee, but if there was a time in the comics where they had to leave the Moon and a government guy said "you can stay here", I'd accept that as an answer, even if the 2nd season, if it happens, could go in a different direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### There are no clues as to the location of the new Inhumans home in the MCU.

The location is suggested by the "official" (who isn't a government official as far as I am aware) who works for "the Boss" (unknown at this time).

> Louise brought Medusa to her place of work, Callisto Aerospace in California. Together, they made her skeptical supervisor George Ashland (Tom Wright) aware of the Inhumans’ existence. When Crystal (Isabelle Cornish) teleported into the room with Lockjaw, George finally took Louise seriously. George promised he would speak to ‘the Boss’ about the Inhumans and find them a new refuge once they evacuate the moon. George even suggested he “knows a place” the Inhumans can decamp to.
>
> <sup>[Source](https://screenrant.com/marvel-inhumans-season-1-finale-unanswered-questions/)</sup>

The *city* of Attilan has had several locations though:

> Attilan (also called The Hidden Land) – Home of the Inhumans. Originally an island in the North Atlantic Ocean, it has moved several times, including to the Andes, Himalayas, to the Blue Area on the Moon, the homeworld of the alien Kree, Hala. More recently Attilan was destroyed during the events of Infinity by Black Bolt when he detonates the Terrigen Bomb, the remains of Attilan now reside within New York, in the Hudson .
>
> <sup>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Features_of_the_Marvel_Universe#Attilan)</sup>

That said [Inhumans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inhumans) have made homes in various *fictional* locations in the comics including Latveria & Genosha.

They have also made homes in Wisconsin in some comic variations.

Comment: Thank you.   I'm impressed by how much detail you have on this, even with the uncertainties.

Comment: I just read Wikipedia...wasn't that hard. :)

Comment: LOL.  (Silly me).